# How to move a WPF shape using an animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to move a shape using an animation and am currently using the following code.  However this does not result in the object actually moving, it just seems to change the location the object is rendered in, which is expected given we are setting the crossHair.RenterTransform.

EDIT:
To clarify - I am using the animation to simulate what an input file instructions contain and as a result think I can only build the animations in code when parsing the input files.  I could be wrong about this but can't see how one could do this in XAML.  The input file format is not in XAML.

Because there are a number of sequential moves contained in the input file I an currently using the shapes current position as the start point for the next animation, however this does not work because it seems the animation is not actually moving the shape.

As a work around I am now changing the shapes actual position in the animations completion handler.  This seems to be working.

So the question remains as to how can I use the same transform to actually move the shape rather than simply rendering it in a different position ?

```
private Storyboard MoveCrossHairToPoint(double x, double y)
        {
            // Adjust for crosshair size so its centered on the x
            double xPos = x;
            double yPos = y;

            double xStart = Canvas.GetLeft(crossHair)+crossHair.Width/2;
            double yStart = Canvas.GetTop(crossHair)+crossHair.Height/2;

            // Create a NameScope for the page so that 
            // we can use Storyboards.
            NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

            // Create a MatrixTransform. This transform 
            // will be used to move the crossHair.
            MatrixTransform crossHairMatrixTransform = new MatrixTransform();
            crossHair.RenderTransform = crossHairMatrixTransform;


            // Register the transform's name with the page 
            // so that it can be targeted by a Storyboard. 
            this.RegisterName("MoveCrossHairMatrixTransform", crossHairMatrixTransform);

            // Create the animation path.
            PathGeometry animationPath = new PathGeometry();
            PathFigure pFigure = new PathFigure();
            pFigure.StartPoint = new Point(xStart, yStart);
            LineSegment lineSegment = new LineSegment(new Point(x, y),true);


            pFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment);
            animationPath.Figures.Add(pFigure);

            // Create a path to follow
            Path path = new Path();
            path.Data = animationPath;
            path.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

            this.bedCanvas.Children.Add(path);

            // Freeze the PathGeometry for performance benefits.
            animationPath.Freeze();

            // Create a MatrixAnimationUsingPath to move the 
            // button along the path by animating 
            // its MatrixTransform.
            MatrixAnimationUsingPath matrixAnimation =
                new MatrixAnimationUsingPath();
            matrixAnimation.PathGeometry = animationPath;

            double time = GetTimeForVelocityOverPath(animationPath, this.velocityMove);

            matrixAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);
            //matrixAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.;

            // Set the animation's DoesRotateWithTangent property 
            // to true so that rotates the rectangle in addition 
            // to moving it.
            matrixAnimation.DoesRotateWithTangent = false;           

            // Set the animation to target the Matrix property 
            // of the MatrixTransform named "ButtonMatrixTransform".
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(matrixAnimation, "MoveCrossHairMatrixTransform");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(matrixAnimation,
                new PropertyPath(MatrixTransform.MatrixProperty));

            // Create a Storyboard to contain and apply the animation.
            Storyboard pathAnimationStoryboard = new Storyboard();
            pathAnimationStoryboard.Children.Add(matrixAnimation);

            return pathAnimationStoryboard;

        }
```

Comment: First, it would be better if you would declare the animation in XAML rather than trying to put it all together in C#. The XAML compiler would do a lot of the heavy-lifting for you. Second, while it's not clear why you care whether the actual shape location is animated versus the render transform, if you want the location to be animated instead, why not just have the animation animate the shape's position properties (i.e. `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top`) instead of the render transform?

Comment: In any case, without a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example that shows clearly what you're doing now, along with a statement explaining exactly how the output of the code now is different from what you actually want, it will be difficult if not impossible to offer a real answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho see additional explanation in the question.

Comment: Thanks. It's possible to parse XAML at runtime, but I see now given your specific scenario why you're building the animations in code-behind. That said, the question's still not entirely clear to me. You can use the `Transform.Transform()` method to apply the `Transform` object to a `Point` value. But is that really better in your scenario than just animating the actual location directly? And assuming it is, can you be more clear about what _exactly_ you're having trouble with? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on including a good code example.